# facebook graph api tutorial getting error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am implementing facebook graph api in iphone using these tutorials http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app
but when i tapped facebook login buttom getting error on nslog file like this

```
2013-01-09 18:50:54.509 FBFun[3279:11303] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> Application tried to present modally an active controller <ViewController: 0x75446a0>.
```

i try to solve the problem by the  answer posted on this link
[New error in iOS 5: WebKit discarded an uncaught exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812061/new-error-in-ios-5-webkit-discarded-an-uncaught-exception)
this is answer on the link

```
-(void)checkLoginRequired:(NSString *)urlString {
    NSLog(@"Url: %@",urlString);
    if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"login.php"].location != NSNotFound && [urlString rangeOfString:@"refid"].location == NSNotFound) {
            [_delegate displayRequired];
    } else if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"user_denied"].location != NSNotFound) {
         [_delegate closeTapped];
    }
}
```

but i am not succedded kindly anyone have answer regarding this post please share with me

Answer (score 1):

Leave that tutorial:

Use this one, easy for you and is in steps:

Download Facebook New SDK from here, you don't need to make seperate calls like you were doing earlier in the ray's tutorial:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/ios/
```

Simplest of the tutorials for the beginners to use and access Graph API/FQL etc from facebook's SDK :

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hey There I Got The Same issue in the code to impement Graph Api using 
[RayWenderLich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app)
but solved it after hours of research and some code debugging.

The Code I Changed for my convinience.

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

  NSString *urlString = request.URL.absoluteString;

  [self checkForAccessToken:urlString];

  if (self.isViewLoaded && self.view.window) {

  ```
     // viewController is visible

     return TRUE;
  ```

  }

  [self checkLoginRequired:urlString];

  return TRUE;

}

-(void)checkLoginRequired:(NSString *)urlString {

```
    NSLog(@"Url: %@",urlString);

    if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"login.php"].location != NSNotFound && [urlString rangeOfString:@"refid"].location == NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"Login Required");
        [_delegate displayRequired];

    } else if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"login_success"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"login_success");

       //any thing you want to do after log in success.
    }
```